# Oracle erro PLS-00103 ao fazer INSERT

Tags: oracle

Não consigo entender esse erro de sintaxe do Oracle:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE

v_idEmp INTEGER: = &numero_funcionario;
v_nome VARCHAR(30): = '&nome';
v_sobrenome VARCHAR(30): = '&sobrenome';
v_email VARCHAR(30): = '&email';
v_tel VARCHAR(15): = '&tel';
v_idCargo VARCHAR: = '&idCargo';
v_salario DOUBLE: = &salario;
v_comissao NUMBER(2): = 200;
v_managerId INTEGER: = &managerId;
v_deptoId INTEGER: = &deptoId;

BEGIN

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES(EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, PHONE_NUMBER, HIRE_DATE, JOB_ID, SALARY, COMMISSION_PCT, MANAGER_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID)
VALUES(v_idEmp, 'v_nome', 'v_sobrenome', 'v_email', 'v_tel', sysdate, 'v_idCargo', v_salario, v_comissao, v_managerId, v_deptoId);


END;
/
```

Emite esse erro:

> Relatório de erros - ORA-06550: linha 8, coluna 20: PLS-00103:
>   Encontrado o símbolo "=" quando um dos seguintes símbolos era
>   esperado:
>
> precisão    O símbolo "precisão" foi substituído por "=" para
>   continuar.
>      06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"    *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.    *Action:

Alguém pode ajudar?

Comment: O Oracle não diferencia `: =` de `:=`?

Comment: Pois é, o operador é `:=`, os dois símbolos juntos. Não pode ter esse espaço entre eles.

Comment: Mesmo sem o espaço ele indica o mesmo erro. Na verdade o codigo esta sem os espaços, eles apareceram ao coloca-lo no post.

Answer (score 2):

Creio ter aspas demais ....

segue a solução proposta , não pude testar todavia

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE

v_idEmp INTEGER := &numero_funcionario;
v_nome VARCHAR(30) := &nome;
v_sobrenome VARCHAR(30) := &sobrenome;
v_email VARCHAR(30) := &email;
v_tel VARCHAR(15) := &tel;
v_idCargo VARCHAR := &idCargo;
v_salario DOUBLE := &salario;
v_comissao NUMBER(2) := 200;
v_managerId INTEGER := &managerId;
v_deptoId INTEGER := &deptoId;

BEGIN

INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES(EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, PHONE_NUMBER, HIRE_DATE, JOB_ID, SALARY, COMMISSION_PCT, MANAGER_ID, DEPARTMENT_ID)
VALUES(v_idEmp, v_nome, v_sobrenome, v_email, v_tel, sysdate, v_idCargo, v_salario, v_comissao, v_managerId, v_deptoId);


END;
/
```

Comment: Obs não atentei para o : = corrija para:=

Comment: Olá, o mesmo erro persiste
Relatório de erros -
ORA-06550: linha 9, coluna 17:
PLS-00103: Encontrado o símbolo "=" quando um dos seguintes símbolos era esperado:

   precisão
O símbolo "precisão" foi substituído por "=" para continuar.
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: Fiz uma edição , tente novamente

Comment: Continua o mesmo erro, sabe me dizer se esse simbolo "precisão" seria o tamanho do dado? Ele indica o erro na linha 9 onde está o a variável para o num de telefone.

Comment: Pode ser um valor com tamanho acima do limite do campo;